# How are composition series for two isomorphic groups related?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are groups, $G\cong H$, and 
$$G=N_{0}\geq N_1\geq \dots \geq N_s ={e_G}$$
and
$$H=M_{0}\geq M_1\geq \dots \geq M_t ={e_H}$$
are composition series for $G$ and $H$, what can be said about the relationship between the $N_i$s and the $M_i$s?

By Jordan-Holder, we know that any two composition series for a particular group have the same length, and that there is a 1-1 correspondence between factors of any two composition series under which corresponding factors are isomorphic.

Does the isomorphism $G\cong H$ allow us to conclude that $s=t$ in the above example, and that each $N_i$ is isomorphic to some $M_j$ and vice-versa? If so, can you explain explicitly how it follows from Jordan-Holder or otherwise?

Thanks for the help, I am new to this concept.

Comment: Yes, it follows from Jordan-Holder. Show that you can use an isomorphism between two groups $G$ and $H$ to write down a bijection between their composition series that respects factors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how does the isomorphism of $N_{j}$ with some $M_{i}$ follow from the isomorphism of composition factors? Could you elaborate in more details?

Answer (score 1):

Because of isomorphism in $G$ and $H$, your question can be reduced to simple one: *if we consider two composition series of same group $G$, what can be said about them?* The answer, you know well, is that the composition factors are isomorphic.

Hence now instead of saying $G$ and $H$ are same, if we consider them as *isomorphic*, then still same answer comes in terms of *isomorphism*: composition factors of $G$ and $H$ are *isomorphic* up to permutation.